# Phoenix Framework: set "expires" attribute for response cookies

Tags: cookies, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm working with Phoenix `1.2.1` and Elixir `1.3.4`.

I need to set the [`Expires`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2.1) attribute for a response cookie.
I can**not** use the `Max-Age` attribute instead.

Unfortunately the [`Plug.Conn.put_response_cookie/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#put_resp_cookie/4) function does not support an `expires` option. In fact, even though I can get something like this in my controller:

```
conn.resp_cookies["my_cookie_name"]
=> %{expires: "Tue, 17-Oct-2017 02:24:24 GMT", path: "/", value: "foo"}
```

The `expires` value is ignored and not returned in the `Set-Cookie` response header.

I think I could set the `Set-Cookie` header directly, but I can't use [`Plug.Conn.put_resp_header/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#put_resp_header/3) because apparently it overrides values and ensures uniqueness of the keys, and will not work if I try to set multiple `Set-Cookie` headers for different cookies.

Am I missing something obvious? Is there a specific function that I have not found?
Is this the expected behavior (if yes, why?) or am I doing something wrong?

### update

I've had a look at how the cookies are encoded in [`Plug.Conn.Cookies.encode/2`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/blob/v1.2.2/lib/plug/conn/cookies.ex#L62-L77), so it looks like I first have to convert my expiration times to `Max-Age` values, and then Plug will convert them back. Doesn't sound like the most efficient way to do it.

Is there any well known way to work around the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A working solution has been [suggested by the Plug maintainers](https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/issues/465#issuecomment-254780967), and addresses the fact that `Plug.Conn.put_resp_header/3` will override already set headers.

```
def prepend_response_header(conn, key, value) do
  %{conn | resp_headers: [{key, value} | conn.resp_headers]}
end
```

This will work like `Plug.Conn.put_resp_header/3`, but will allow to set the same header multiple times.